# Anyone know what car this is?

Tags: vw, car, vehicle-identification

What car do you think this is? My guess is new 2017 VW Tiguan.

Taken 8 April 2016 in Brisbane , Australia.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where and when were these images taken?

Comment: The VW Zebra-mobile is designed to blend nicely into any safari excursion.

Comment: @JPhi1618 taken 8-April-2016 in Brisbane, Australia

Comment: Looks like someone watched Daktari on TV in their impressionable years, and wants the Game Warden look, but couldn't afford the landrover.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a custom-wrapped VW Touareg.

It looks like it belongs to an employee at Vehicle Wraps, a custom-wrap shop in Brisbane. There is [a gallery on their Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1624431417821849.1073741894.1411370919127901&type=3) documenting the process and the gallery description reads:

> Bape no more we have wrapped the Touareg to match my Moth Sailing Boat

It's not clear [what year the model is](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/27988/16272), but the pictures were uploaded in November, and have a lot of good detail. So, someone else may be able to identify the year based on the pictures.

Comment: Good find.  This is _the_ answer for sure.

Answer (score 12):

Judging from the lights and body shapes I would say it looks like a 2015 Volkswagen Touareg.

[image: Touareg]

Comment: It would be odd for a manufacturer to camouflage a car that's already in production

Comment: @Zaid Who says it's camouflaged? I'd say it's a pretty cool paintjob/wrapjob/stickerjob by the owner.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing that is definitely dazzle paint applied by a manufacturer to disguise the form of a prototype vehicle. For example. Red Bull Racing at the start of 2016 http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/02/02/253D644100000578-0-image-a-1_1422885708165.jpg

Comment: @Gusdor I agree that it looks like it, but it not necessarily is. Looks a little clean to be intended for camouflaging the body shapes as well. Either way, it's not clear how old the photo is in the first place.

Comment: Maybe they are disguising the fact that they haven't changed the body much this year.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Mitsubishi Outlander ?

[Bing Image Search Results](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=mitsubishi+outlander&view=detailv2&&id=AED0F3383168D8DB27732CFFD0B797F121B3A2EE&selectedIndex=46&ccid=qolfl%2bUA&simid=608055567763571954&thid=OIP.Maa895f97e50061959c0f136e5abd79e7o0&ajaxhist=0)

Comment: Including at least one image in your answer would be helpful, but it's moot now since the exact car has been found.